# VLC output to stdout instead of opening a new window

Tags: command-line, powershell, vlc-media-player

I am trying to get VLC to play an on-the-fly generated stream (MJPEG, just a bunch of JPGs written to the stdout of the generator program one after the other) which is piped to `vlc -` where the dash should get VLC to play from stdin.

Instead of playing, VLC spazes out, the title of its window alternatives between something about `fd://` (I am not using named pipes) and the normal VLC title. Other than that, the window is completely frozen and it tries to show the error log, but it's just too frozen for it to show anything.

In trying to fix this, I have started researching how to get output from VLC. I tried running `./vlc.exe`, `./vlc.exe -vvv` and `% ./vlc.exe` in PowerShell and `vlc` and `vlc -vvv` in CMD. None of these commands produces any output.

When I run `vlc -H` or `vlc ---intf rc`, VLC opens a new window with the output, but the terminal window where I ran it from (I am on Windows, trying PowerShell and CMD) receives no output.

Can I make VLC use the original window it is ran from instead of the one it shows on its own?

My hope is in doing this I will be able to see the error output when streaming my MJPEG stream to `vlc -` and validate my suspicion that it is interpreting the `stdin` input as commands instead of as a stream, which I can then try to proceed and fix.

Comment: You are not showing any PowerShell code, that you are using to do this. So, this can be looked as a VLC issue, not a PowerShell one. Even with PowerShell involved, VLC, is an external command, that thus PowerShell will shell out to cmd.exe to run it. So, please clarify how this is a PowerShell issue for you. Show your code.

Comment: As far as getting VLC output in the terminal where I ran it, I expected "./vlc.exe -H" (for example) to be it, like with any other command. Like I said, that opens a new window, VLCs own terminal. I'm not claiming this is a PowerShell issue, I just don't know how to prevent it and have that output stay in my terminal. I am happy with a PS based or a VLC based solution.